# Unable to create new AdyenCheckout in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adyen

I am new to Adyen and relatively new to Javascript and REACT. I am trying to use the Adyen dropin components in REACT but cannot create a new AdyenCheckout component.

I have loaded the Adyen Javascript in componentDidMount using the following code:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://checkoutshopper- 
test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.0.0/adyen.js";
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

And I am trying to create the AdyenCheckout component using the code below:

```
const configuration = {
locale: "en_US",
environment: "test",
originKey: "YOUR_ORIGIN_KEY",
paymentMethodsResponse: this.state.paymentMethodsResponse,
};

const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
const dropin = checkout
    .create('dropin', {
        onSubmit: (state, dropin) => {
        },
        onAdditionalDetails: (state, dropin) => {
        }
    })
.mount('#dropin');`
```

Or, by changing 
`new AdyenCheckout(configuration)` 
to `new window.AdyenCheckout(configuration)`,

as people seem to have had success with this syntax in the past.

> Using `new AdyenCheckout(configuration)`

, I get the error `AdyenCheckout is not defined`.

> Using `new window.AdyenCheckout(configuration)`

, I get the error `TypeError: window.AdyenCheckout is not a constructor`.

I am sure its something pretty simple I am doing wrong so if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

What's going on here is that you're trying to initiate AdyenCheckout before the script being actually loaded.

The easiest solution for these king of cases is to add a script tag in the HTML document. That way the script will be loaded before the React App is initiated.

That being said, since you'll only use the script in a specific section, adding the script tag in your React app does make sense.

To solve the issue, just move all the functionality related to AdyenCheckout to a method you call once the script is loaded:

```
class AdyenDropin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initAdyenCheckout = this.initAdyenCheckout.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.0.0/adyen.js";
    script.onload = this.initAdyenCheckout; // Wait until the script is loaded before initiating AdyenCheckout
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  initAdyenCheckout() {
    // ...
```

Here you have a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropin-component-56vlt).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidMount` to initialize the AdyenCheckout object as it will have access to DOM.

```js
class AdyenDropin extends Component {
  contructor(props){
    this.checkout = {};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/3.0.0/adyen.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    
    const configuration = {
      locale: "en_US",
      environment: "test",
      originKey: "YOUR_ORIGIN_KEY",
      paymentMethodsResponse: this.state.paymentMethodsResponse,
    };

    const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
    const dropin = checkout
      .create('dropin', {
        onSubmit: (state, dropin) => {
        },
        onAdditionalDetails: (state, dropin) => {
        }
      })
      .mount('#dropin');`
    }
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div id="dropin"></div>
  }
}
```